# Google Sheets - Find and replace specific characters in a cell

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need to find some specific characters in a cell and replace them with other characters.
So far I can do that by using :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"★","•",0),"<b>","",0),"</b>","",0),"✔ ","",0)
```

However, this formula will become very long if I need to replace a lot of characters. Is there any way to reduce the duplicate parts, especially when I need to replace some characters with only the other one. Ex: Replace **,** , ✔ with "" as example above.
Demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wX9mEykCMjeotTRTg_jSMcm9Mm7WM0kPTetRwGLzaYU/edit#gid=0

Comment: Your Google Doc is not publicly viewable

Comment: Done, sorry for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheets (but not Excel) has a handy formula, `REGEXREPLACE`, that will let you do what you need:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"<b>|</b>|✔",""),"★","•")
```

If you need to remove any more characters, just add them after the checkmark, separated by `|`.

Comment: This will replace every letter b in my text. Please check the example sheet